# How can I make an image auto-resize so the width is 100% and the height adjusted accordingly?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have the following simple XAML page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Test.UserGuides.VPN">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="10,10,10,10">
                <Label Margin="10,10,10,10" Text="How to connect to VPN." HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                <Label Margin="10,10,10,10" Text="If you have a corporate notebook, look for the Cisco AnyConnect application. Either in your start menu, on your desktop, or in your taskbar." />
                <Image x:Name="imgVPN1" Margin="10,10,10,10" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                <Label Margin="10,10,10,10" Text="Select your region and press the Connect button." />
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

In the constructor, I call a method to load the images:

```
private void LoadImages()
{
    imgVPN1.Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit;
    ImageSource imagesrc = ImageSource.FromResource("Test.Files.CiscoAnyConnect.PNG");
    imgVPN1.Source = imagesrc;
}
```

The result looks like this on my (rather large, high DPI) phone:

[imgur link 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNj5P.jpg)

Of course, I want the image to automatically expand so it takes up the entire width of the screen. While maintaining the aspect ratio. But how can I achieve this? I've already tried putting the Aspect to "AspectFill", and added

```
imgVPN1.WidthRequest = Application.Current.MainPage.Width;
```

To the LoadImages method, but that makes the end result look like this:

[imgur link 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOwSq.jpg)

I've been toying around with various HorizontalOptions, VerticalOptions, Aspects, GridView, StackLayouts,... The end result is always either the first or the second screenshot. So how can I achieve what I want here?

Comment: what is your image size to experiment?

Comment: @YuriS The dimension of the CiscoAnyConnect.PNG image is 411x 191.

If I could get those values it would be easy to set the HeightRequest to the aspect ratio, but it seems to be near impossible to do that with Xamarin.Forms from my research the past hours.

Comment: can you post it somewhere so I don't need to rectreate similar?

Comment: Sure thing: http://imgur.com/Z487WqB

Comment: There are 2 bugs created. One for grid and one for StackLayout. Bugs confirmed but not fixed. I would try to use relative layout if you need to scale a picture. Sorry https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=27729 and
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=55294

Comment: There are 2 options. You can get image like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/qbh520ngp7dm3b3/ImageInStackLayout.png?dl=0 or use relative layout

Comment: @YuriS and how did you achieve that? Looks like huge margins or Heightrequest?

Comment: that's the bug. the image scales but keeps original height. Is that acceptable? I am working on relative layout. It is tricky with the bug but doable. But I am having problems with scrolling which I am trying to solve

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149630/discussion-between-yuri-s-and-matthias).

Comment: Only solution I've found up until now: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62171219/4058784

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is what can be done. XML almost didn't change, I just removed image Layout Options

```
<ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="10,10,10,10">
                <Label Margin="10,10,10,10" Text="How to connect to VPN." HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                <Label Margin="10,10,10,10" Text="If you have a corporate notebook, look for the Cisco AnyConnect application. Either in your start menu, on your desktop, or in your taskbar." />
                <Image x:Name="imgVPN1" Margin="10,10,10,10" />
                <Label Margin="10,10,10,10" Text="Select your region and press the Connect button." />
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

After implementing everything in relative layout which also was not simple (I have the code if anybody needs it let me know) I found easier way. The key point is that image doesn't scale correctly and occupies too much space in height. But we know the size ratio of this image so we can use it. In the code we need to override OnSizeAllocated because in constructor the width is unknown yet. Then it's easy

```
protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
{
    base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);
    imgVPN1.WidthRequest = width;
    imgVPN1.HeightRequest = width / 2.152; //given that image is 411 x 191
}
```

You could use other width than page with if you want. For example you could use stack layout width to consider margins for more accuracy but this is already tuning. Or you actually could use the image width itself like that

```
 protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
 {
     base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);
     double needHeight=imgVPN1.Width / 2.152;
     if (imgVPN1.Height != needHeight)
         imgVPN1.HeightRequest = needHeight;
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Yuri S. Thank you for this. Indeed I also managed to semi-fix/workaround the problem by manually specifying the HeightRequest. However for that to work you either need to know the dimensions of the image or the aspect ratio. And since you can't seem to get them programatically, you would need to hardcode this for every image.

Anyway, I appreciate your help. And I think this will be the only way to do it for now. I will test your solution in my project.

Comment: Where are your images? If they are in resources you know the the ratio in advance. if they downloaded you can probably find out the ratio.

Comment: Thank you! I nearly spent an entire day trying to figure this out!

Comment: @primehalo glad it helped

Comment: In my opinion it's a huge embarrassment for Xamarin Forms that this has to be done via code in such a hacky way. Not to mention that this only works when image size is known.

Comment: Solution works! One side note, you can't compare two doubles this way: `if (imgVPN1.Height != needHeight)` you always get `true`

Answer (score -1):

Here is what you need.

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout Margin="20" Spacing="10">
            <Label Text="How to connect to VPN." HorizontalOptions="Center" />
            <Label Text="If you have a corporate notebook, look for the Cisco AnyConnect application. Either in your start menu, on your desktop, or in your taskbar." />
            <Image Source="yourimage.jpg" HorizontalOptions="Fill" />
            <Label Text="Select your region and press the Connect button." />
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that just produces the results from the first screenshot.

Comment: @Matthias It's working correctly for me. What version XF are you using? and it's reproduced in Android or iOS?

Comment: Or could try set WidthRequest=2000 on your image with my code?